# How to make opaque glass lamp shade

Tags: materials, glass

[image]

How do i make material like this lampshade?
Let light through, but not be transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make something not too complicated you could just mix a *Diffuse* node with a *Translucent* one, with a *Noise* texture as factor to make the glass more or less opaque. Also, put a Glossy before the *Material Output* so that it reflects its environment, and plug the *Noise* into a *Bump* node to add some bumps.

[image: *enter image description here*]

Answer (score 1):

Thnx, but i solved it before i read your post.
This is what i got
[image]
EDIT:
Here's how i did it
[image]

Comment: nice, so maybe share the nodes organization  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Best way I would think of doing this is UV Unwrap the lamp shade, add the colourful image texture and then mix the image texture, which is essentially your diffuse colour, with an emission shader. Then play with the emisson strength on the emission node and slider on the mix node.